# Keep tryning to resolve a class Does not name a Type

Tags: c++, class

The problem I had was like said in the title a `"Effect" does not name a type` , so I searched and found about decleration , then initialization , so I added a `class Effect;` line in my code, giving another error about `field has incomplete type` , when searching that I found it was due to a forward declaration , so now I don't know what to do ....
The problem I think is that I have a looping inclusion , Here are the files :

#### Errored Code :

```
#ifndef RUNE_HPP_INCLUDED
#define RUNE_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Ressources.hpp"
#include "Effect.hpp"

class Effect; //Declaration of Effect

class Rune{
public:
    Rune();
    target getTarget();
    effect getEffectName();
private:
    Effect eff;  //Error is here , with this code it is incomplete type
};

#endif // RUNE_HPP_INCLUDED
```

#### Effect.hpp :

```
#ifndef EFFECT_HPP_INCLUDED
#define EFFECT_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Ressources.hpp"
#include "Tile.hpp"

class Effect{ // Init of Effect
public:
    Effect();
    effect getName();
    target getTarg();
    void actionTile(Tile& tileTarget);
private:
    effect name;
    target targ;
};

#endif // EFFECT_HPP_INCLUDED
```

#### Tile.hpp

```
#ifndef TILE_HPP_INCLUDED
#define TILE_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "TileStatic.hpp"
#include "TileDynamic.hpp"

class Tile{
public:

private:
    TileStatic staticTile;
    TileDynamic dynamicTile;
};

#endif // TILE_HPP_INCLUDED
```

#### TileDyanmic.hpp  , loop is looped :

```
#ifndef TILEDYNAMIC_HPP_INCLUDED
#define TILEDYNAMIC_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Trap.hpp"
#include "Rune.hpp"

class TileDynamic{
public:

private:
    Rune rune;
    Trap trap;
};

#endif // TILEDYNAMIC_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Ressources.hpp doesn't include project files , it is just constants and some structs. Here they are :

```
#ifndef RESSOURCES_HPP_INCLUDED
#define RESSOURCES_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

enum effect{
    ZERO_EFFECT,
    INST_DAMAGE,
    POISON,
    SLOW,
    STUN,
    SILENCE,
    HEAL
};
enum target{
    ZERO_TARGET,
    SELF,
    ENEMY,
    TILE
};

sf::Texture getNoTexture();
const sf::Texture NO_TEXTURE = getNoTexture();

struct coord{
    int x;
    int y;
};
coord getZeroCoord();
const coord ZERO_COORD = getZeroCoord();
```

#endif // RESSOURCES_HPP_INCLUDED

I hope anyone knows a way to solve my problem , which I think is an inclusion problem.

Comment: I guess what really happened here is that you wildly mixed upper and lower case. In C++, `effect` and `Effect` are completely unrelated names. (By the way, you also spell "resources" incorrectly.)

Comment: No there are two Effect and effect , one is a class ,other a enum , i'll add the Resources file too)

Comment: Such naming conventions border on cde obfuscation guidelines...

Comment: Forward declarations help for pointers to types only, not for making concrete instances. The forward declaration of `Effect` in `Rune.hpp` isn't helping.

Answer (score -1):

First letters are low case every function's return type, but your classes names starts with highcase. I think that's the problem.

Comment: Sorry if not, maybe i don't know c++ enough, and said something stupid.

Comment: No, this is not the issue. It is legal (if confusing) to have types names that differ only in case.